# CSS Not being rendered, and error: "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:4353."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localhost

My website was working fine on Friday using localhost, and now none of the css is being rendered, and if I try to click on a link, I get an error that a connection can't be established. I opened up another project before looking at this one, and ever since, I have had problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly states, your server is not running.
You need to start the development server.

Comment: No, it is started. It shows the first page, it just doesn't show any subsequent pages. I press the run button in visual studio.

Comment: Do you see the server in the notification tray?

Comment: @shawleigh17 4543 is not the same port as the one from the error message in your title.

Comment: Ok, so what would be causing that? I have 4543 in the properties window for the website. I don't know where it is getting 4353.

Comment: By default, it chooses a random port every time.  Or, 4353 might be the other project.

Comment: I think the real question is, if your project is supposedly running on port 4543, then why is your browser trying to go to port 4353? You said it works at first; at what point does the browser decide to start using the wrong port? Are you hard-coding any links with port numbers in them?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't really work at first -- perhaps what you're seeing is a cached copy of that page (cached by your browser).

Comment: That could have been the case. I don't believe that I have any hard-coded port numbers anywhere in my code. I had originally had it select a dynamic port number, but perhaps the other project used a specific port number. I changed the project to use 4353 and it works, now. Thank you very much for everyone's help.